# Add a column to a view in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to add a column to a view in snowflake or whenever I want to add a column I must recreate the view using

```
Create or replace view view_example as (
 Select * from customers
)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The key point is that `SELECT *` inside the view definition is not "dynamic". Related: [Snowflake SQL Compilation Error: View Definition Declared but view Query Produced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68038013/snowflake-sql-compilation-error-view-definition-declared-but-view-query-produce/68044884#68044884)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snowflake supports `ALTER VIEW` but the docs state that to change it's definition you have to `DROP` and re-create (or `CREATE OR REPLACE` as in the question).

> Note that you cannot use this command to change the definition for a view. To change the view definition, you must drop the view and then recreate it.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-view.html