# After deleting columns in view/table of snowflake how to update the reference in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

This is a duplicate question of [Snowflake SQL Compilation Error: View Definition Declared but view Query Produced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68038013/snowflake-sql-compilation-error-view-definition-declared-but-view-query-produce)
It doesn't get satisfactory answer. Also here I am deleting column instead of adding. For adding column there is workaround (mentioned below) but it doesn't work when deleting column.

I am using snowflake for data storage and cleaning and powerbi desktop for creating charts. On powerbi I have sourced a view from snowflake as direct query. I have created a few charts. 2 of the columns originally presented in the snowflake view are not being used. So I deleted this from the view. Now it is showing error. [image: error shot].
What is a proper way to adapt the powerbi to change made in this type of change in source?

I have tried following:

1. deleted the table in powerbi and sourced it again.
2. In power query editor tried to refresh the preview. This step worked when I added column in view instead of deleting
3. In power query editor deleted the navigation and again created it and choose required 15 columns using home -> 'choose columns'

The table in power query editor shows the data but it shows error when doing refresh preview and in charts.

Comment: If its direct query go inside of the select query that you have build and specify the columns in the query. Can you show the data load steps in the query editor?